# Point of intersection of $f_a(x)=ax^{2}+3x+1$ and $g_b(x)=\frac{b}{x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

For what values of $a$ and $b$, the two functions $f_a(x)=ax^2+3x+1$ and $g_b(x)=\frac{b}{x}$ are tangent to each other at a point where the $x\text{-coordinate}=1$.

The points of intersection are where:
$f_a(1)=g_b(1)$

which gives 
$$a+4=b\text{ and } b-4=a$$

Now what to do with this information? Or if my approach is right?

Comment: Is it complete question ? maybe it was :intersect is in x axis ,x=1 .

Comment: with this information , you have one equation and 2 variable !

Comment: Yes. Expressing a condition $f(x)=\frac{b}{h(x)}$ in therms of $b$ gives $b=h(x)\,f(x)$, where we've not even considered $x=1$ in particular. For your functions this equation says $b=x\,(ax^2+3x+1)$, which is a relation between $b, a$ and $x$. You're interested in the point $x=1$, leaving you with $b=a+4$, a relation between $b$ and $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the slope of tangent of $f_{a}(x)=ax^2+3x+1$ at a general point is given as $$\frac{d}{dx}(f_{a}(x))=\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2+3x+1)$$$$\color{red}{f'_{a}(x)=2ax+3}$$ Similarly, the slope of tangent of $g_{b}(x)=\frac{b}{x}$ at a general point is given as $$\frac{d}{dx}(g_{b}(x))=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)$$$$\color{red}{g'_{b}(x)=-\frac{b}{x^2}}$$ Since, the curves $f_{a}(x)$ & $g_{b}(x)$ are tangent to each other at a point having $x=1$ Thus the angle between tangents at $x=1$ must be zero i.e. slopes of common tangent at both the curves are equal hence, we have $$$$

$$(f'_{a}(x))_{x=1}=(g'_{b}(x))_{x=1}$$ $$\left(2ax+3\right)_{x=1}=\left(-\frac{b}{x^2}\right)_{x=1}$$ $$2a+3=-b$$ $$\bbox[4pt, border: 1px solid blue;] {\color{blue}{2a+b+3=0}}$$ Above is the required relation between $a$ & $b$. Hence there are infinitely many real values of $a$ & $b$ satisfying the above relation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your approach is right, and you cannot gather any further information about $a$ and $b$.

There are just infinitely many pairs of $a$'s and $b$'s that satisfy the requirements of the problem, and you have shown all the requirements on the $a$'s and $b$'s.

So you are done! So report your answer, and start on another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't “to be tangent to each other in $x_0$”  defined by $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and $g'(x_0)=f'(x_0)$? know that $f(1)=g(1)$ and $f'(1)=g'(1)$.  In this case we derive two linear equations with solutions $a=-7/3$ and $b=5/3$.